# How to scale a Bezier Curves t value while keeping its initial and final derivatives the same?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bezier

there are a lot of answers for scaling a bezier curve's position, but i want to scale its t value. I have found a solution for this, but the problem is once i scale my t value my velocity changes.

By scaling t value i mean scaling the range of t from 0,1 to 0,n
The way im doing this currently is dividing whatever increment i use by the maximum t value i need, and converting it into a t with the range of 0,1
curT += deltaTime
t = curT/maxT

this leads to my derivatives being incorrect. So they must be corrected by dividing them by MaxT to the power of whatever order derivative

D1 = d1 / MaxT ^ 1
D2 = d2 / MaxT^2

This is due to the formula for velocity and acceleration.
Velocity = d/t
acceleration = d/t^2

I have derived the formula for initial velocity to be

Vi = 2P1 - 2P2

and because i have initial velocity with some algebra i can derive P2

P2 = Vi/2 - p1

my problem is, this seems to scale incorrectly. If i change my maxT then my initial velocity will change aswell.
how do i maintain a initial velocity while changing my scaling factor?

Relevant Code:

```
public partial struct AccelSimple : IJobEntity
{
    public float delta;
    void Execute(ref PhysicsVelocity velocity, ref BezierCurvePoints curve, ref Rotation rotation)
    {
        float t = curve.curTime / curve.timeScale;

        //calculate velocity at any point on curve
        velocity.Linear =
            (curve.p1 * (-2 + 2 * t) +
            curve.p2 * (2 - 4 * t) +
            curve.p4 * (2 * t)) / curve.timeScale;

        curve.curTime += delta;
    }
}
 var handle = Entities.WithAll<FinishedMovementTag>().WithoutBurst().ForEach((Entity e,
         ref BezierCurvePoints curve, ref PatrolIndex index, in DynamicBuffer<PatrolPoints> points,
          in Translation translation, in PhysicsVelocity velocity, in AccelerationSpeed acceleration) =>
        {
            Debug.Log(curve.p4 - translation.Value);

            if (index.value >= points.Length - 1) index.value = 0;
            else index.value++;

            //due to floating point and physics simulation errors cannot precalculate Curve
            //Starting Point of Curve
            curve.p1 = translation.Value;

            //Velocity of t=0
            curve.p2 = (curve.p1 + (velocity.Linear / 2));

            //end position of curve
            curve.p4 = points[index.value].Position;
            
            //rough approximation of length of curve //was hoping this would allow math hacks to get velocity scaling factor
            float mag = Vector3.Magnitude(curve.p1 - curve.p4);

            //Time it should take to get to end of curve
            curve.timeScale = mag / acceleration.value;
            curve.curTime = 0;

            ecb.RemoveComponent(e, typeof(FinishedMovementTag));
            ecb.AddComponent(e, typeof(SimpleAccelTag));
        }).Schedule(this.Dependency);
```

this is with a second order bezier curve, i could use a third order but i dont really care about the velocity on exit so it seems like an unneccesary constraint.

Im using bezier curves because they model a curve being effected by derivatives of position, which seemed ideal for a physics path, as it has velocity acceleration jerk ect. built in. however to use the physical properties of the curve, i need to scale t up or down by a given degree.

My formula for the most part does exactly what i want it to do, it only fails around connecting 2 curves, and slowing down when a curve extends to far which is likely due to an incorrect formula on my account.

Comment: What do you mean "scale its t value"? The representations I have seen define the t as `t >= 0 && t <= 1`, so 'scaling' it makes little sense to me. What is the actual goal you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: instead of t >= 0 && t <=1
t >= 0 && t<= finalTime
im using it for its physics properties, but i need it to be in var time not in 1 time

Comment: That still does not makes any sense to me. Bezier curves are designed to allow you control of the derivative at t == 0 and t == 1. You could calculate points outside the 0-1 interval and use them to create a new Bezier curve with desired start/end and derivatives, but I fail to see how it is useful. And Bezier curves are designed for computer graphics, I'm not sure what 'physical properties' you are referring to.

Comment: im not calculating t past 1, im just making 1 20 instead

a bezier curve of N Degree models a point with n-1 position Derivatives.
in this case a third order bezier curve models a point with initial position, initial velocity and initial acceleration.

in this case im using it with predefined start position end position and start velocity, and using it to model the velocity change of a ship. and it has the acceleration calculation built in.

Comment: It's still pretty unclear what you;re actually trying to do: you can't scale `t`, the end. A Bezier curve is literally defined as running from `t=0` to `t=1`: if you need to slow down travel, then you increase `t` from 0 to 1 slower/in smaller interval steps. It _also_ sounds like you need to update your post to explain what you're trying to _achieve_ first, in your post. Your most recent comment, for example, should absolutely not be a comment, but part of your problem description, so give [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) a read-through and update your post accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications. I have tried to edit my question accordingly. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a general answer, because i believe my use case is quite unique.
long story short, it was a math mistake/ factor I didn't consider.
I do properly scale my velocity according to time, but while doing that I scale down my initial velocity significantly. the solution is to multiply my initial velocity calculation by the amount I scale it down by.

Time = Vector3.mag(p4-p1);

p2 = p1 + (initial-velocity * .5f * time);